# html meta declaration which code is correct

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta

Which one I should use in order to cover max. browser versions 1 or 2 or both are equivalent.

1.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

2.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: @Quentin very similar but a bit different concern. I want to ask is, in old browsers where html5 doctype is not recognized the meta will be valid or not.

Comment: No, it is a duplicate. This is a more *specific* question, but still a subset of the duplicate and answered there.

Comment: Check this link https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/MetaCharsetAttribute says

Answer (score 0):

You have provided us and yourself with the answer!

They both are equivalent (to be noted: Since, HTML5)! :/ So use them as per usage or your choice.

The only benefit for me, would be that the second one is lesser to type so it would save some time! Otherwise, they both are just same.

Answer (score -1):

With the first meta you are only defining the character set of the page, with the second one your defining the content type of the page plus the character set. Second one is more complete, and in some cases it will prevent errors.

Comment: No user agent has *ever* paid attention to the media type in a meta tag.

Comment: I thought in some e-mail clients it does, but i may be wrong.

Comment: No. Email clients will use the Content-Type SMTP header (or the equivalent bit in a multipart MIME email).